# Can an internal SSD and it's connector survive everyday plug&unplug?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, ssd, external-hard-drive

I am thinking about carrying my internal SSD with me. Doing so my 'computer' will be with me everywhere. This is better than carrying a persistence flash disk, because I won't need to sync my files constantly and I won't need to buy a big expensive flash disk.

I will unplug it from my laptop in the morning and plug in again in the evening. And I will use it with SATA to USB cable on other computers during the day.

Question is, are SSDs and connectors in laptops durable enough to survive this?

Comment: Your biggest problem is going to accidentally breaking the SATA plug either on the SSD or the laptop.  If you put in it a hard external case that didn't allow the connectors to bend at all that would improve your odds of survival.  If your using a simple USB to SATA adapter with no case around it the odds of snapping off the SATA connector increase.

Comment: This is harakiri. Buy a cheap portable hard disk and sync the internal and external disks with some sync utility. And, by the way, what about backups ?

Comment: You might also find issues using the same SSD as a boot drive on different computers unless they are configured *exactly* the same. If there is a hardware difference on the same model, such as the manufacturer substituting different audio or WiFi components on later models, this might  not work well.

Comment: Well, I feel you are right.